# Rails: assets precompilation makes the app fail in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails v3.2.8, Capistrano v2.13.5 and Unicorn 4.3.1 and when I deploy I get a very weird behavior.

If the following conditions are satisfied:

- There are assets to precompile
- A new class or method has been added in the code base
- Some part of the app uses this new class or method

When assets are precompiled during deploy process, before unicorn is restarted, I get exceptions on the web app telling me that the new class or method is undefined.

It should not happen since unicorn has not been restarted yet and thus should not be aware of the code using the new class.

It's like if the classes cache was cleared and the autoload would reload my models.

Any idea of what could cause this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you paste the error stack trace ?

Comment: It's not always the same, usually it's a classical undefined method or undefined constant error.

Comment: If you're not running in development mode (or with class caching off) you must be restarting unicorn somewhere - watch your unicorn processes for master/old master.  It may be buried in your cap recipes somewhere.

Comment: I am restarting unicorn but it happens after the assets compilation. I call `cap production deploy` on my dev instance but the commands are done on the production server and should then not be impacted.